# ImportError: No module named _multiprocessing on python 2.7.3

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to do:

```
import multiprocessing
```

but get the error:

```
ERROR    2015-01-21 18:40:49,457 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nir/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/nir/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/home/nir/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/root/workspace/spring-nova-827/Main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import multiprocessing
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    import _multiprocessing
  File "/home/nir/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 898, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named _multiprocessing
```

I looked this problem up, but could not find a solution

Answer (score 0):

You are running in a sand-boxed environment that will not allow you to import certain modules in the standard library (`multiprocessing`) in this case.

Why do you need `multiprocessing`? It may be that you can get away with using `threading`, though that may come with a performance hit depending on what you are trying to achieve. I've also noticed that `concurrent.futures` is also recommended for use with App Engine.

See the sections on "The Sandbox" and "Pure Python". https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/

Comment: hi, yes  decided to use concurrent.futures, but because i'm using python 2.7 this modul need to be installed. I tried installing it using: sudo pip install futures but it still gives me : ImportError: No module named concurrent.futures. Do you know what's the solution ?

Comment: Seems I was wrong about `concurrent.futures`. See this API reference on how to spawn threads that persist after after a request. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/background_thread